# Jquery window resizing and click event

Tags: jquery, resize, window, width

i am trying to make responsive web but i got trouble with resizing widow width.
when window width is smaller than 885, codes in the first if works fine, however when window width is bigger than 885, it has a problem,,,,
even though i block click event(off), when i try to resize again,  in console still have "none"and "block" also click event happens and '.common-a' which is clicked has {opacity:0;}.

below is my code.

```
var $window=$(window);    
    function intoTablet(){    
        var width=$window.width();    
        if(width<=885){    
            $('#wrapping .hidden-gnb .common-ul >li').on('click',function(ee){    
                $(this).siblings().children('.hover-ul-inner').css('display','none');    
                $(this).siblings().children('.common-a').css({'opacity':1});    
                console.log("none");    
                $(this).children('.hover-ul-inner').css('display','table');    
                $(this).children('.common-a').css({'opacity':0});    
                console.log("block");    
            });    
        }    
        if(width>885){    
            $('#wrapping .hidden-gnb .common-ul >li').off('click',function(ee){    
                $(this).siblings().children('.hover-ul-inner').css('display','none');    
                $(this).siblings().children('.common-a').css({'opacity':1});    
                console.log("none");    
                $(this).children('.hover-ul-inner').css('display','table');    
                $(this).children('.common-a').css({'opacity':0});    
                console.log("block");    
            });    
        }    
    }    
    intoTablet();    
    $window.on('resize',function(){    
        intoTablet();    
        console.log("resizing");    
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use off fuction without callback function like

```
  $('#wrapping .hidden-gnb .common-ul >li').off('click');
```

You can add your `.css` function out of `.off()` function and the set the opacity

```
  if(width>885){    
     $('#wrapping .hidden-gnb .common-ul >li').off('click');    
     $(this).children('.common-a').css({'opacity':0});
  }
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zoo8w49v/1/)

Comment: thanks it works almost!! no more console.log("block")and console.log("none").but when making window bigger, '.common-a' is still has opacity:0; value . how can i figure out with this?

Comment: @JoJay Yep, possible and i updated an answer, may be it solves your  problem.

Comment: but a moment ago i solved like below                                  $('.common-a').css({'opacity':1});
   $('.hover-ul-inner').css('display','table');
   $('#wrapping .hidden-gnb .common-ul >li').off('click');